# why doesn't my jquery click function work after changing element values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

So I'm making a small quiz app with object oriented JS using Object.create cloning method. I have an ol, and a function called showVals() that populates it with lis. That seems to be working fine. What I'm having trouble with is: my li click function to give the attr of ".selected' class seems to work intitially, but after I click to proceed and qn2.showVals() is called it is no longer giving the lis a class of selected when clicked.

The data for qn2 is there. Everything looks normal, except for the click function no longer working (giving the lis the class).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
qn1.showVals();
qn1.setAns(1); // calling question1 answer for now

$('li').click(function(){
$('li').removeAttr("class");
$(this).attr({"class": "selected"});
});

$('.proceed').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('.selected').html() == qn1.ctAns) {
     if (confirm("You are correct")){
    qn2.showVals();
    qn2.setAns(3);
    };
    };
});

});

var qn1 = {
title:"The Mouth of Sauron",
qn: "How did 'The mouth of Sauron' meet his demise?",
img: "images/mouth-sauron.gif",
ans: ["Shot in the back", "Beheaded", "Drowned in a swamp", "Sacrificed"],
setAns: function(x) {
    this.ctAns =  this.ans[x]; //setting correct answer
},
showVals: function(){

    $('#slide-title').text(this.title);

    $('.question-box > p').text(this.qn);

    $('#obj-img').attr("src", this.img);

    $('ol').html('<li>'+this.ans[0]+'</li>'+'<li>'+this.ans[1]+'</li>'+
    '<li>'+this.ans[2]+'</li>'+'<li>'+this.ans[3]+'</li>')
   }
}

var qn2 = Object.create(qn1);
qn2.title = "Golemn";
qn2.qn = "What this dude's name?";
qn2.ans= ["Golemn", "Gimli", "Goober", "Poop"]
qn2.img = "images/golemn.gif";
```

Comment: this is because your click event is binded before your DOM element is changed, you can either bind the event every time you changed your DOM or use a onclick attribute in your li tag

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely because your `li` elements are dynamically added.
You should try using [jQuery on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler), which allows you to bind an event handler to the parent element which must already exists in your DOM, and then you can specify the child/descendant selector that will call the event handler. This child element may still be non-existent at the time you do the event binding. In such a case, you call on() like:

```
$('ol').on('click', 'li', function () {...});
```

where `ol` already exists.

Alternatively, you could always bind your click handler to your dynamically generated `li` elements after you have added them to your DOM. Although I think that is more processor-time consuming as I assume you have to do this for all quiz questions you ask your user.

Comment: This helps. Thanks a lot.